# angular js Argument 'DemoCtrl' is not a

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

signup.html

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form inputdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="inputBasicDemo">

  <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding="">
    <div>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="user.title">
      </md-input-container>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'artistControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
        controller: 'DemoCtrl'
 }).  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/signup'
  });
}]);
```

controller.js

```
angular
.module('inputBasicDemo', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    title: 'Developer',
    email: 'ipsum@lorem.com',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    company: 'Google',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy',
    city: 'Mountain View',
    state: 'CA',
    biography: 'Loves kittens, snowboarding, and can type at 130 WPM.\n\nAnd rumor has it she bouldered up Castle Craig!',
    postalCode: '94043'
  };
  $scope.states = ('AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS ' +
  'MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI ' +
  'WY').split(' ').map(function(state) {
      return {abbrev: state};
    })
}])
```

Getting  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/ng/areq?p0=DemoCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined  error.

while routing the request through app.js and controller facing this issue , however while taking the code form https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input the code is not throwing error.

Please suggest

Comment: Update in Controller.js

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Your module names are different between your `app.js` and your `controller.js`.

You also shouldn't ever set a module's injections in more than one place.

Suggestions:

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'artistControllers',
  'ngMaterial',
  'ngMessages'
]);
```

controller.js

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
// code ommitted
});
```

**ORIGINAL**

Your module names are different between your `app.js` and your `controller.js` so your `DemoCtrl` isn't available to your `myApp` module.

Comment: Hi Simon K, tried with same name , however it did not worked !

Comment: If module names are same , getting following :   Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Comment: Tried that as well , its not working . getting same issue Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Comment: Just noticed your HTML has the attribute `ng-app`. It also has `ng-controller`. Both of these can be removed safely as they are being specified in your `$routeProvider`. At the very least, if you haven't already, the `ng-app` needs to match which ever module name you've gone with.

Comment: problem still persists , I think the issue is with the controller and dependencies.

Comment: Do you know if you have all the correct script tags for the libraries you are trying to inject?

Answer (score 0):

You are decleraring two things to inject to the controller but only use `$scope`.
Add also the `$http` service

```
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

Comment: Hi antoniskamamis , tried that , however it did not worked !